# Infinite counting in Wordpress

Tags: functions

I have this function in Wordpress that counts 10 users by default. I would like to change it from showing 10 users to infinite number. There should be no end to counting. How can I do this?

```
function get_random_followers($userid, $count = 10){

$followers = get_the_author_meta('followers', $userid);

/** if no followers at the moment */
if( !is_array($followers)){
    $return = "";
} else {

    $flw = array_pick($followers, $count);

    $return = '<ul class="widget_follow">' . "\n";
    foreach( $flw as $folow){

        $return .= "<li>";
            $return .= '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url($folow) . '" title="' . get_the_author_meta('display_name', $folow) . '">';
                if( get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $folow ) != "" ) {
                    $return .= '<img src="' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $folow ) . '" alt="" />';
                } else {
                    $return .= get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $folow ), '40' );
                }
            $return .= '</a>';
        $return .= "<li>";

    }
    $return .= '</ul>' . "\n";
}

echo $return;

}
```

Comment: That looks like a custom function. Would you go ahead and include the function in the code?

Comment: Not sure how this is a WP question ... you're using custom functionality and regular old PHP loops.

Comment: Is it possible to add a pagination so when it lists for example 50 followers, to skip to page 2? I have a custom pagination <?php user_pagenavi(); ?> How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a custom function.

It's passing `$count` to a function called `array_pick()` to limit the size of your follower array.  It also looks like `array_pick()` is a custom function.

But you can easily *stop* the function from limiting your count by removing the call to `array_pick()`:

```
function get_random_followers($userid, $count = 10){

    $followers = get_the_author_meta('followers', $userid);

    /** if no followers at the moment */
    if( !is_array($followers)){
        $return = "";
    } else {

        $return = '<ul class="widget_follow">' . "\n";
        foreach( $followers as $folow){

            $return .= "<li>";
                $return .= '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url($folow) . '" title="' . get_the_author_meta('display_name', $folow) . '">';
                    if( get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $folow ) != "" ) {
                        $return .= '<img src="' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_custom_avatar', $folow ) . '" alt="" />';
                    } else {
                        $return .= get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $folow ), '40' );
                    }
                $return .= '</a>';
            $return .= "<li>";

        }
        $return .= '</ul>' . "\n";
    }

    echo $return;

}
```

Instead of turning `$followers` into a 10-item subset (`$flw` in your example), we loop through the entire `$followers` collection.

Comment: Is it possible to add a pagination so when it lists for example 50 followers, to skip to page 2? I have a custom pagination 
    <?php user_pagenavi(); ?> How do I do it?

Comment: Open a new question for that. It's a separate issue.

Comment: I will do as You say :9 Thank You for Your giant help!